# Razor pages in .NET 6 project seem to be compiled with C# 8.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, .net-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core project that I recently upgraded to .NET 6. It compiles fine, but when I open a specific page, it claims I can't use a certain C# 9.0 feature, the [or pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements):

[image]

This is strange as .NET 6 automatically selects C# 10 as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version), and the advanced build settings indicate I haven't selected a different one:

[image]

Also, the same code inside a Controller causes no problems; the problem only appears on .cshtml pages.

This is part of the stacktrace:

```
Exception handler: Error: An error occurred while serving a page.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.CompilationFailedException: One or more compilation failures occurred:
D:\Repos\MySolution\MyProject\Views\Home\TestRun.cshtml(40,17): error CS8400: Feature 'or pattern' is not available in C# 8.0. Please use language version 9.0 or greater.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument, String generatedCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(String relativePath)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler.OnCacheMiss(String normalizedPath)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by explicitly setting the language version by editing the .csproj file:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <Version>1.0.2.4</Version>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

But it turns out the real problem was something different, and I should've paid more attention to the build log:

```
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(134,5): warning NETSDK1182: Targeting .NET 6.0 in Visual Studio 2019 is not supported.
```

To my defense, it's shown in a small view and this message quickly scrolls out of view.

When I run the same code in Visual Studio 2022, it works fine.